# Eclipse disassembly view, can you view disassembly without debugging the program?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, eclipse-cdt, disassembly

I was using the Eclipse-CDT "Disassembly" View while debugging a program (in the "Debugging" Perspective. I found useful the way that Eclipse-CDT has the source code display and assembly code display synchronized.

I would like to peruse the compiler generated assembly code while not running the debugger. I am interested in changing things like:

- compiler flags (for example: -O0, -O1, -O2, -O3)
- changing C code

And then observing the changes in the generated assembly code.

**In Eclipse-CDT, can you view the disassembly without actively debugging the program, yes/no?**

If yes, how?

Maybe Eclipse-CDT isn't the right tool for this. I seem to recall there is a way to prod the compiler into generating a verbose/readable assembly listing with line numbers and annotations back to the original source.

Comment: While in Eclipse-CDT, I just noticed that you can double-click on an object file and the assembly disably is produced. I will have to check this out.

Comment: If you want change source or compiler options and see the asm change, you might want to install a local copy of Matt Godbolt's compiler explorer web interface, where you can run it on part of a large codebase.  (Or use http://gcc.godbolt.org/ online, with special #include syntax for github repos if you need special headers.)  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116), and Matt's CppCon2017 talk: [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4) where he mentions local installs.

Comment: It is a great disappointment that Eclipse does not have this feature. You still have to use objdump to view disassembly interleaved with code but of course this is not as user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in Eclipse-CDT, I just noticed that you can double-click on an object file and the assembly disably is produced. I will have to check this out.

I know you can use the compiler to generate assembly listings too.

I'm sure there are other tools too.